# A-positions where no structural Case is available?

Tags: syntax, cases

I am a little puzzled. Is there any such thing as an A-position where no structural Case is available? The arguments are either a nominative or an accusative (structural Cases) aren't they?

> [...] Since this problem arises from the fact that [+F]NPs can occur
>   in **A-positions where no structural Case is available**, [...]
>   (Kobayashi, K. (1987). A note on bare-NP adverbs. *English
>   Linguistics, 4*, 336-341.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are A-positions where no structural case is assigned. Let me give you some examples from English:

```
(1) The data were classified
(2) They arrived
(3) They seem to have arrived
(4) The data seem to be classified
```

(1) is a passive sentence. The complement position (V [**DP**]) is an A-position where no structural accusative case has been assigned. This position is left without its case (or say the passivized verb does not assign accusative case), this is why the object *the data* has to move to another position where it ends up assigned a nominative. A similar observation carries over to (2) as an unaccusative verb.

The sentences in (3)/(4) are examples of raising to subject. The specifier position (A-position) of an embedded infinitival clause does not assign a nominative case. Again their subjects have to move further in the structure ending up assigned a nominative by a tensed matrix clause.

Notice that (3) combines two A-positions left without case. The first is the embedded A-position (V-complement) of the unaccusative *arrive* and the second is the embedded infinitival position (Spec,IP). The same thing with (4), there are two positions left. The embedded passive V-complement and the embedded infinitival Spec,IP.

These are the two structural case positions left without case in a language like English. This observation, however, varies from one language to another.

Comment: Thanks, Tsutsu. Okay, so the author was talking in perspective of D-structures. I was thinking in terms of only S-structures.

He went on to say, " (... A-positions where no structural Case is available,) one might try to solve this problem by excluding the activation of the [+F]feature from A-positions, i.e., by restricting it to A'-positions or adjunct positions." Would A'-positions be A-positions where no structural Case was assigned?

Comment: Case is assigned at S-structure in GB framework. A'-positions (or adjunct positions) are not assigned case. But elements which were assigned case before may move there, e.g., wh-movement. A' positions would never be A-positions, but A'positions can host elements which were assigned case in A-positions.

Comment: I stand to be corrected: Since V [DP] is in the representation of D-structure as you can tell it from seeing the fact [DP] is moved to the subject position (at S-structure), the A-position you said initially is in D-structure. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, Tsutsu, one more thing. What are you referring to when you say 'elements which "were" assigned case "before"'? I'm a non-native speaker. I couldn't get it. Thanks.

Comment: I might have had to say 'What were you referring to when you said ...?'

Comment: Yes of course, it was a D-structure position because it was assigned an internal  role there. What I meant by elements that were assigned case before is wh-movement. Both subject/object wh-movement are assigned both theta role & case before moving to A’-positions.

Comment: You've been so helpful. In order to help myself understand the above, I would like to further ask you a few queries: 1. An argument does not have to be assigned Case at D-structure level. Am I right? 2. A slot such as the subject position of an infinitival clause and the object position of a passivized verb can hold an NP as an argument at D-structure level. Correct? 3. A' positions at S-structure level could have been A positions at D-structure level. Right? Thanks, Tsutsu. I'm so indebted.

Comment: 1. Right. Structural case is assigned at SS. 2 Right. Passives have arguments in complement positions at DS, infinitivals have PRO (big pro) as subjects at DS. 3 Wrong. A’-positions do not change label and become A-positions. I didn’t say this in my answer nor in my comments. I said A’-positions (which are assigned neither theta nor case) can receive elements moved from A-positions.

Comment: Thanks so much, Tsutsu. Much appreciated. 3. Kobayashi (1987) says, "We have observed  the cases where introduction of the notion of default Case into the grammar undermines the theoretical basis of Move α or of-Insertion. Since this problem arises from the fact  that [+F]NPs can occur in A-position where no structural Case is available, one might try to solve this problem by excluding the activation of the [+F] feature from A-positions, i.e., by restricting it to A'-positions or adjunct positions."

Comment: You may want to ignore the former part of this quote because it has nothing to do with the nature of my current question, but he is saying one might consider excluding moving a given word from the A-position (at DS level) ; in other words, keeping it to the A'-position or the adjunct position (at SS level). This caused me to wonder if an AP in a DS could be an A'P in the SS. Please enlighten me, Tsutsu. Your help has been marvelous.

Comment: Note: (at SS level) and (at DS level) are my interpretations.

Comment: Which example Was given in this situation where an A’-position can become A-position?

Comment: The other way around, Tsutsu. According to Kobayashi (1987), one might erroneously hold an argument in an A-position, as a given sentence transforms from the DS to the SS, which is an A' position (Adjunct position) at SS. For example: (DS) /e did not seem [/AP [/NP the time] [/A ripe]. ---> (SS) [/NP/i the time] did not seem [/AP e/i [/A ripe]]. = *It did not seem the time ripe. [/NP the time] is in an A-position because it is in the subject position of [/A ripe]. However, it is in an adjunct position at SS.

Comment: (Kobayashi (1987) says [/NP the time] could be mistakenly looked on as licensed to stay as what he thinks to be an fallible theory, the [+F]NP theory, gives an Oblique status to the NP) Thanks again, Tsutsu.

Comment: I don’t think there’s an A’-position in this sentence. There’s no adjunct and no specifier of complementizer involved. The NP ‘the time’ is not licensed in this position given that adjectives do not assign case, so instead of raising to be case marked by ‘seem’ in subject position, this position is filled by an expletive. So ungrammaticality follows from the ‘the time’ which is not case marked. It has nothing to do with A/A’-positions

Comment: Your insight is absolutely right. His account uses the term an A-position referring to the position of [/NP the time] because it's the subject position of [/A ripe] at DS, and then an A'-position since it is not assigned either nominative or accusative Case at SS. He says restricting the NP in the A-position, then called A'-position at SS, is attributable to an assumption that the NP internally provides itself with Oblique Case, provided it is not given a structural Case otherwise. It doesn't have to Move-α.

Comment: But you are right that the NP is obviously not case marked. I just wondered if A-position at DS could be called A'-position at SS, as in the example, like I inferred that was how he uses the terminology. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes I think you’re.

Comment: Thanks, Tsutsu. Much obliged.